# clutch being depressed engages starter

Tags: clutch, starter

I have replaced the GEM module and the ignition. WHen ever I push the clutch the starter engages even with the key out. The driver side window does not roll up and the lights come on and off. What else do I need to check for or does anyone know of a site I can go to to help me solve my problem? Thanks Eric

Comment: Interesting issues - you have obviously got the electrics screwed up, perhaps an incorrect module version, or short circuits...however, without more information (type of car, versions, specific symptoms, what checks you have currently carried out etc) the question is not going to get useful answers. You can edit your question to update with this info.

Comment: Welcome to the site. In order to get a good answer for your question you will need provide detailed information on the problem. Please edit you question to provide this information, once that is done I will reopen the question.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the correct module? If so, warranty it and get a replacement. The vehicle is equipped to disable the starter unless the clutch is depressed. Your circuit is stuck on START and becomes aactive when the clutch override is disabled by the clutch being depressed. As Rory mentioned - it is impossible to offer a definitive diagnosis without being able to lay hands upon the vehicle, but I echo his sentiment that you have a defective or incorrect module.